# Access Denied for MYSQL ERROR 1045

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, mysql-python

I just got a new macbook pro (OS X 10.8.2) and am attempting to get mysql set up on it. So far I've been able to get it installed but I cannot get my root user access (or any user for that matter). I plan on using this for `Python`, on my other computer I only use MYSQL (no MAMP) and I prefer to keep it that way.

For reference, I did the following:

`$ alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
$ sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
$ alias mysqladmin=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin`

When i enter `mysql` or `mysql -u root -p` it gives me this:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

or

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jmitch'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` 
Depending on which phrasing I use

MYSQL is running in my system preferences. Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password

Answer (score 22):

Maybe updating the package the updater overwrote the root password.

To restore it:

Stop mysqld deamons.

```
$ sudo service mysqld stop
```

Go  to  mysql/bin directory

```
$ cd /usr/bin
```

Start a mysql deamon with this option:

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Open another terminal and open a mysql session to execute this:

```
$ mysql

mysql> use mysql;

see Note1 below for next line.
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD_HERE') WHERE user = 'root';

mysql> exit;
```

Now kill the mysqld_safe process and restart mysqld normally:

```
$ sudo service mysqld start
```

***Note1:*** `password` is the column name in table `mysql.user` prior to version 5.7. After which it became `authentication_string`. Change your update statement accordingly.

Comment: `$ sudo service mysql stop`  returns `sudo: service: command not found`

Comment: running the daemon in sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables mode may not be really required, i tried without it and still it solved my problem (this was on mac 10.9)

Comment: this works for me on OS X Mavericks 10.9 after having a lot of Access Denied when typing in 'mysql -u root -p', thanks!

Comment: Please refer to this if you encountered "Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'":
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31122246/1371949

Comment: yes, the column name is `authentication_string` in version 5.7

Comment: There is no service called mysqld in Ubuntu, where the correct command would be `service mysql stop`

Comment: In mysql 14.14 with Ubuntu Xenial, the above doesn't work. Meaning that the original error persists even after the described sequence of commands.

Comment: @user1283068 mysqld? Look it up for your distro?

Comment: Look what up for my distro? Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: @user1283068 look up how you start and stop services for your distro. I am sorry it makes no sense to you. I cannot tutor everyone new to stuff

Comment: @Drew I wasn't asking what the name of the service was, I was just pointing out an error in the reply. As you can see I specifically mention the correct name of the service.

Comment: If in case someone gets service command not found error: 
use this instead:

To stop:  
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

To start:
 sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

It is recommended to first check the status of your mysql server first.

These are the steps for mysql 5.7

Answer (score 6):

on Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks I used the 'mysql.server' script in the support-files directory instead of the mysqld_safe and service script.

```
$sudo ./mysql.server stop
$sudo ./mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables
$ mysql
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD_HERE') WHERE user = 'root';
mysql> exit;
$sudo ./mysql.server stop
$sudo ./mysql.server start
```

Comment: I dont have any database named `mysql`, I have two databases: `information_schema` and `test`. I connected through this command: ` mysql -h127.0.0.1` as via just `mysql` I was getting this err: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue trying to access MAMP's MySQL through the terminal on Mountain Lion.

The --no-defaults flag solved it for me.

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --no-defaults -u root -proot -h localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that for MySQL 5.7 simply changing the authentication_string column doesn't work. This is because MySQL never actually uses those values for root authentication, it uses a plugin. As far as I can tell this plugin verifies that you are also root on the host account (so you have to sudo mysql -u root).

The only way I was able to get this to work was to run this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET authentication_string=PASSWORD(''), plugin=''
WHERE mysql.user = 'root';
```

It should also be noted that the official MySQL documentation for 5.7 never mentions this. Following this documentation to the letter gets you nowhere at all.

Comment: I'm running 5.7* on OS X 10.12.3 and can no longer use the `mysql stop/start` alias, getting the error of the question. Your above answer looks promising, but gives: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'mysql.user' in 'where clause'`?