# Resetting a MySQL admin password? (Other solutions don't seem to be working)

Tags: mysql, database

Sorry this is such a basic question, but I'm struggling to get any of the solutions I've found online working. Basically I've managed to lose my MySQL password for my local machine and now I'm completely locked out

I've tried resetting it using this command:

> mysqladmin password example_new_password

But that gives me an error saying "mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed. Error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

And I've also tried following these instructions (https://goo.gl/lvV1jo), but when there's no .pid file or anything named 'mysqld' in /var/lib/mysql so I couldn't do much from there

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I'm a little lost at the moment

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have mentioned that. I'm using Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: try to access with `-p` for example  `mysql -u root -p password`

Comment: @authprivate  Really??? He just said that he lost his password...

Comment: I can walk you thru my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13480374/1816093  where it say sudu this sudo that just do the appropriate start / stop / restart for **YOUR** distro

Comment: As long as you can start and stop mysql (with sudo or service or whatever), and can find my.cnf I can help you.

Comment: Thanks @DrewPierce, I managed to get it working thanks to your linked post!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-N.N
```

Where N.N is your MySQL version.

If that doesn't work, have a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: I did "mysqladmin --version" which gave me "Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.5.43", then I entered "dkpg-reconfigure mysql-server-8.43" but I got an error saying "mysql-server-8.42 is not installed"?

I got up to "start the mysql client process using this command" on the ubuntu page, but entering "mysql -u root" spits out this error


> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Comment: Your mysql version is 5.5.43 not 8.42...There is no 8.43...the latest version of mysql is only 5.7.XX...also from the terminal do a `ps aux | grep mysql` to see if mysql is even running...+1 @Ben Fried

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed it was version 8.42 since it said "Ver 8.42". I'm getting the exact same error when I change it to 5.5.43 though, and MySQL if definitely running.