# Can't start sudo mysqld with --skip-grant-tables

Tags: mysql

I am looking at [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) to reset the mysql root password on an Ubuntu development machine.

```
#> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
```

Seems to work but then

```
#> sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
2016-09-04 15:27:13 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-09-04 15:27:13 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.31-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) starting as process 8892 ...
```

This process exits. Afterwards, when I try

```
#> mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: don't do the skip networking part. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13480374

Comment: Otherwise the port is not open and connects have to occur thru named pipes or shared memory.