# #1045 error in MYSQL and phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mysql-error-1045

So i've found a few people on here that had the same issue, but I have not been able to resolve mine.

I downloaded XAMPP and was able to use phpmyadmin without a problem at first. I then tried setting a password for the root user, and then started getting this error message. When I try and log in to MYSQL from the command line, I get the same error unless I login with `mysql -u root`

At first I thought the issue was a password, but I got rid of the original password and I still get the error. I've managed to get rid of all other mysql users, and when I run SHOW GRANTS, it shows that the root user has all privileges, so I'm unsure why I can't log in to MYSQL normally, or phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the  C Drive /(Your Local Server Folder, WAMP/MAMP/XAMPP)/ APPS / PHPMYADMIN /config.inc.php file, find the line of code $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] =' ', and type the password that you have already set for the root, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thats what I had seen on a few of the other answered questions, but I can't seem to find the config file. There is nothing within the XAMPP application package I can see. I am on a mac if that makes any difference. Thank you for the response

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480170/access-denied-for-mysql-error-1045 maybe it can be helpful